# How prove this hypersingular operator $(T\psi)((z(t))$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset  R^2$  be a simply connected
bounded domain with inﬁnitely diﬀerentiable boundary  $\partial\Omega$and unit normal
vector $v$ directed into the exterior of $\Omega$
$$\Phi{(x,y)}=\dfrac{i}{4}H^{(1)}_{0}(k|x-y|),x\neq y$$
we denote the fundamental solution to the two-dimensional Helmholtz equation in terms of the ﬁrst kind Hankel function of order zero

where
the  Helmholtz equation
$$\Delta u+k^2u=0, \mbox{in}   R^2\overline{\Omega}$$
and 
$$(T\psi)(x):=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v(x)}\int_{\partial\Omega}\dfrac{\partial\Phi{(x,y)}}{\partial v(y)}\psi{(y)}ds(y),x\in\partial\Omega.$$

let: $$x=z(t)=(z_{1}(t),z_{2}(t)),y=z(\tau)=(z_{1}(\tau),z_{2}(\tau)),-1\le t,\tau\le 1$$
show that:
$$(T\psi)((z(t))=\dfrac{1}{|z'(t)|}\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\tau-t}\dfrac{d}{d\tau}\psi(z(\tau))+L(t,\tau)\psi(z(\tau))\right)d\tau$$

where
$$L(t,\tau)=-\dfrac{i}{2}\dfrac{z'(t)\{z(t)-z(\tau)\}z'(\tau)\{z(t)-z(\tau)\}}{|z(t)-z(\tau)|^2}\left(k^2H^{(1)}_{0}(k|z(t)-z(\tau)|)-\dfrac{2kH^{(1)}_{1}(k|z(t)-z(\tau)|)}{ |z(t)-z(\tau)|}\right)-\dfrac{ik}{2}\dfrac{z'(t)z'(\tau)}{|z(t)-z(\tau)|}H^{(1)}_{1}(k|z(t)-z(\tau)|)-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\dfrac{1}{(\tau-t)^2}+\dfrac{ik^2}{2}H^{(1)}_{0}(k|z(t)-z(\tau)|)z'(t)z'(\tau)$$
This results is from this paper:http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042703005867

and
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042794000737

and I have Calculate for a few days,at last I failure

since I have post this question:[The Helmholtz equation: How prove this $T\psi{(x)}\in\Omega$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608889/the-helmholtz-equation-how-prove-this-t-psix-in-omega)

and 
[How prove this $\displaystyle\lim_{\tau\to t}f(t,\tau)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{x'_{1}(t)x''_{2}(t)-x'_{2}(t)x''_{1}(t)}{[x'_{1}(t)]^2+[x'_{2}(t)]^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605287/how-prove-this-displaystyle-lim-tau-to-tft-tau-frac12-pi-fracx-1)

I want use this  results $$(T\psi)(x)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s(x)}\int_{\partial\Omega}\Phi{(x,y)}\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial s}(y)ds(y)+k^2v(x)\cdot\int_{\partial \Omega}\Phi{(x,y)}v(y)\psi{(y)}ds(y),x\in\partial\Omega $$
I know this problem is limit problem,But I feel the pressure to prove this

.Thank you for your help